# Вопрос про абстракцию и полиморфизм в java

Tags: java, ооп

Загвоздка такова: по отдельности я более-менее понимаю, о чем эти 2 парадигмы:

- Абстрактный класс с методами - своего рода шаблон,который наследуют
  другие классы. Объект такого класса нет смысла создавать, т.к. он
  абстрактен, но наследники могут использовать его методы и
  переопределять их.
- Полиморфизм - это возможность использовать метод с одним именем в
  разных классах, но по-разному его реализовывать, переопределяя. Также
  понимаю,что в принципе одну систему можно построить как на базе
  абстрактного класса,так и используя полиморфизм.

Но что использовать лучше и чем они отличаются - я не понимаю, не хватает совсем немного,чтобы додумать. Поясните, пожалуйста, что и как, если можно на примерах.
Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: може уточнить литературу которую читали по этому вопросу?

Comment: Кэти Сьера "Изучаем Java"
Книга Хорстмана, просматривал книгу Блинова "Промышленное прогарммирование", перечитал куча статей  схабра и других источников типа devcolibri.может потому  и запутался

Comment: Предлагаю вам начать вот с чего: отформатируйте вопрос, разделите его на нормальные предложения, расставьте знаки препинания и пробелы. Такая каша — это проявление неуважения к читателям, и реакция на него будет точно такая же.

Comment: Понял вас.Со всем согласен.Впредь буду форматировать текст.Спасибо за совет

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Это тесносвязанные базовые понятия ООП, они дополняют друг друга. Поэтому нельзя говорить "что использовать лучше". Как вы написали,

> абстрактный класс с методами своего рода шаблон,который наследуют другие классы

Так вот, вы задаете определенный шаблон для дальнейшей реализации полиморфизма.
Когда от этого абстрактного класса у вас будут 2 или более наследника, реализующие абстрактные методы. Это и будет полиморфизм. 
Также, часто помогает осознать что это сама расшифровка слова. "поли" - означает много, "морфа" - форма. Полиморфизм - много форм. Есть одна абстракция, и есть много реальных форм этой абстракции. Ещё стоит помнить, что полиморфизм в ООП не ограничивается этим, перегрузка методов - также является полиморфизмом: много форм у одного метода.

Ещё раз, не разделяйте понятия ООП и не пытайтесь выбрать "что лучше" - все базовые принципы ООП - костяк, и только используя все кости сразу вы добьетесь красивого результата (конечно, меру знать нужно, так что злоупотреблять не стоит).

**UPD.** касательно вашего комментария:

> если мы имеем супер-класс,но не абстрактный и наследуем от него другие классы,использующие его метод. можно ведь при этом делать супер-класс не абстрактным. например класс "фигура" и классы-наследники "квадрат", "круг".все будут иметь метод "рисовать".

```
abstract public class Shape {    
    int Color;                       
    Coordinates StartPoint;         
    abstract public void Draw();
}

class Point extends Shape {          
    public void draw() {        
        // Здесь рисуется точка
    }
}

class Circle extends Shape {           
    public void draw() {           
        // Здесь рисуется круг
    }
}

class Square extends Shape {            
    public void draw() {           
        // Здесь рисуется квадрат
    }
}
```

Если суперкласс будет неабстрактным в данной ситуации, то либо придется писать реализацию `draw()` для класса `Shape`, которую не особо понятно как делать, либо же вообще Shape не будет ничего знать про метод draw() и тогда не получится сделать то, что описано ниже.

Зачем все это вообще нужно? Потому что когда-нибудь у вас будет много разных фигур, например, в массиве:

```
List<Shape> shapes = shapes(); // Получим откуда-то его.
shapes.forEach(Shape::draw);
```

И всё, мы отрисовали все квадраты, круги, точки. И для каждой фигуры вызвался свой метод draw.

Это так же ответ на вопрос:

> а зачем нам выделять из нескольких классов общие черты и плодить еще один дополнительный класс?

Comment: вроде немного стало понятнее. хорошо, а вот к примеру если мы имеем супер-класс,но не абстрактный и наследуем от него другие классы,использующие его метод. можно ведь при этом делать супер-класс не абстрактным. например класс "фигура" и классы-наследники "квадрат", "круг".все будут иметь метод "рисовать".но в каждом наследнике он будет реализован по-своему.то есть полиморфизм будет,но не будет абстракции. и теперь если сделаем супер-класс абстрактным,то получим абстрактный метод "рисовать" и его унаследует круг с квадратом и будут иметь описываемый метод "рисовать". похожие ситуации,или нет?

Comment: @Iga Конечно, можно. Класс не обязан быть абстрактным, чтобы от него можно было наследоваться и переопределять методы. В [этом ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491275/199822) можно убрать модификатор `abstract` у класса `Animal`, и код будет работать так же. Модификатор `abstract` требуется для класса, если в классе есть абстрактные методы; если абстрактных методов нет, но хочется запретить создание экземпляров класса, то добавляется `abstract`.

Comment: @Iga Абстракция будет и в случае с *фигурой*: абстракция подразумевает выделение общих черт объектов и вынесения их в отдельный супер-класс. В зависимости от конкретной задачи абстракция может быть разной. Например, *квадрат* и *прямоугольник* — какой из этих объектов является *более общим*, и таким образом, более *абстрактным*? Это зависит от решаемой задачи.

Comment: стало еще лучше в плане понимания. а зачем нам выделять из нескольких классов общие черты и плодить еще один дополнительный класс?или все зависит от нужд программиста и проекта?

Comment: @Iga, дополнил ответ

Comment: то есть, если мы в родительском классе хотим прописать метод,который будет потом во всех классах-потомках, то мы просто вынуждены сделать его абстрактным? ведь получается,что наследники могут быть одного вида,но отличаться друг от друга каким-то признаками и для них не задашь 1 конкретный метод, который будет работать в каждом из них. я правильно понимаю? и чтобы избежать абстракции мы не пишем в родительский класс этот метод,просто в наследниках каждый раз будем прописывать его реализацию(для каждого)

Comment: @Iga, не обязательно всегда абстрактным. Зависит от ситуации. Например, в приведенном примере с фигурами усложним структуру: вместо `Square` отнаследуем от `Shape` прямоугольник - `Rectangle`. У прямоугольника реализуем `draw` который рисует прямоугольник. А далее, от прямоугольника отнаследуем уже квадрат - частный случай прямоугольника. И в нем уже не "реализуем" `draw`, а "переопределим" его относительно прямоугольника (квадрат ведь нарисовать чуть проще, чем прямоугольник). Получится структура `Shape` -> `Rectangle` -> `Square`.

Comment: @Iga, у вас неплохое понимание всего происходящего, а ответы на возникающие у вас вопросы будут приходить с опытом. Ситуаций множество, и где что и как применить будет вижно в каждом конкретном случае. Пока учитесь, рекомендую вместо рассматривания синтетических примером попытаться что-то сделать небольшое свое, например маленькую игру вроде змейки или лабиринта. Практикуйтесь, наступайте на свои грабли и будет понимание ;)

Comment: да,квадрат-это прямоугольник, у которого все стороны равны,поэтому в этом примере у нас как я понимаю проявится всего лишь полиморфизм. 
но если к примеру у нас от Shape, унаследуются квадрат, треугольник и круг, то  либо Shape мы делаем абстрактным и вписываем абстрактный метод draw();либо оставляем его как есть но без этого метода, а сам метод в треугольнике, квадрате и круге будет прописываться по-своему(тоже полиморфизм). я правильно понимаю?
спасибо,но хочется в принцип вникнуть.все парадигмы более-менее уложились, а тут не хватает совсем чуть-чуть, чтоб "дошло")

Comment: @Iga Вы правильно понимаете. Но не стоит особо обращать внимаение на то что _квадрат-это прямоугольник_ — это редко помогает. Используйте наследование — для полиморфного поведение. Полиморфное поведение — для реализации шаблонов (GoF) и все. Для других вещей наследование — это плохая вещь  (в большинстве случаев). И `draw` может в `Shape` быть. Что-то вроде `draw{drawPolyline(toPolyline());}` `toPolyline()` — полиморфный (паттерн тепмлэйт метод, или декоратор) :)

Comment: @Iga, если вы не пропишите метод `draw` в `Shape`, вы не сможете воспользоваться примером с отрисовкой всех фигур в одном цикле из ответа (две строчки кода внизу моего ответа). Там у `Shape` вызывается `draw`, но подставляется нужная реализация для каждого наследника. В этом вся прелесть. Если у `Shape` не будет прописано метода `draw`, вы так сделать не сможете.

Answer (score 5):

Абстрактный класс может не реализовывать некоторые методы, и тогда наследники должны реализовать их.

Это тесно связано с полиморфизмом. Абстрактный метод может использоваться в реализации других методов, но конкретная реализация метода будет предоставлена позже.

Абстрактный класс и полиморфизм не взаимозаменяемые понятия. Абстрактный класс является одним из инструментов полиморфизма.

Например, есть некий компонент:

```
public abstract class Component {

    public abstract int getPreferredSize();

    public int getMinimumSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    public int getMaximumSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }
}
```

По умолчанию, минимальный и максимальный размер равняется предпочитаемому.

Наследники класса должны обязательно предоставить реализацию метода `getPreferredSize()` и, по мере необходимости, могут переопределять `getMinimumSize()` и/или `getMaximumSize()`.

Answer (score 4):

Полиморфизм это не просто переопределение методов. Допустим есть абстрактный класс `Animals`

```
public abstract class Animals {

public void say(){
        System.out.println("I'm animals");
    }
}
```

Есть два наследника `Cat` и `Dog`

```
public class Cat extends Animals {

@Override
public void say() {
        System.out.println("I'm cat");
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animals {

@Override
public void say() {
        System.out.println("I'm dog");
    }
}
```

Ну и наш класс Main

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Animals> list = new ArrayList<Animals>();
        list.add(new Cat());
        list.add(new Dog());
        list.add(new Cat());
        list.add(new Dog());
        for (Animals an : list) {
            an.say();
        }
    }
}
```

И хоть у нас ссылка типа animals будет вызван метод именно из класса Cat и Dog.

```
I'm cat
I'm dog
I'm cat
I'm dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Переопределение абстрактных методов абстрактного класса, это относится к полиморфизму.
Так же к полиморфизму относится перегрузка функций.

Answer (score 0):

Эти два принципа тесно связаны. Смотрите. Главная реализация абстракции в ООП - это интерфейсы. Но сокрытие конкретной реализации за интерфейсом можно рассматривать как проявление инкапсуляции.

И цели обоих этих концепций пересекаются - это переиспользование кода, сокращение кода, гибкость системы.

А еще полиморфизм (в контексте абстрактных классов и интерфейсов) можно рассматривать как средство достижения абстракции.